Using IntelliCode in visual studio 2022 accepts suggestions commented out
Thank you very much for entering this question, my English is not very good so I used machine translation. When I use Visual Studio's IntelliCode to accept suggestions, everything is automatically commented out.

I tried searching this question on google and couldn't find an answer.How should I deal with this situation?Thank you very much!

Your question is not too clear.  What suggestion?
Also in the code image you are declaring a class within another class, are you sure that is what you want to do?  That doesn't seem syntactically correct, and possibly why Intellisense is wanting to comment it out.  But I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

@ross-youngblood Thank you for your reply,what is shown in the code picture is that after I typed Enter in a class, github copilot and IntelliCode gave suggested codes based on my other codes (the gray part that appeared after typing Enter, they are several methods), I accept the suggestions Finally, the compiler commented all these codes. I'm not sure why.  -_-!

Ross's answer may be the reason. I tested it and it doesn't happen on my machine. Can you try it simply and see if the problem still occurs after reinstalling these differences?
